# How to create a type that wraps around mutable vectors?

Tags: haskell, generics, vector

I'm trying to create a type, a 2D Matrix, that wraps around mutable vectors. I want a few operations such as set, get. The problem is that I have absolutely no idea on how to get the types for it to work. I've tried several things, but I'm really just shooting on the dark because there is absolutely no explanation nowhere on how to do this. See:

```
data Matrix v s a = Matrix { size :: (Int,Int), buffer :: v s a } -- ?? Wrong
newMatrix = ??
set (x,y) mat = ??
get (x,y) val mat = ??
```

Take, for example, [the official documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.5/docs/Data-Vector-Generic-Mutable.html). Where is the constructor? What does `v` and `a` in `class MVector v a where` mean? What the heck is `m (v (PrimState m) a)`? Is that the "type" of a generic mutable vector? What is `m` and `v`? What even is PrimState?

Comment: `newMatrix` is going to have to have a type `(PrimMonad m, MVector v a) => arg1 -> arg2 -> argN -> m (Matrix v s a)`, since you'll need to use `Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.new` in order to construct it.

Comment: `PrimState` is a type that is associated to a `PrimMonad`. There are only two instances of `PrimMonad`: `ST s` and `IO`. `PrimState` is therefore either `RealWorld` or `s` (from `ST s`). But those things are hidden in [`Control.Monad.Primitive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Primitive.html#t:PrimMonad).

Comment: Note: The documentation you linked is ancient. That's `vector 0.5` from 2010. Have a look at [`vector 0.10.12.*`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html) instead, although the type is still mostly the same.

Comment: It may be elucidating to first write those functions for `IOVector`, then simply generalize the types to allow them to be polymorphic in vector type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user2407038 noted, it is easier to restrict yourself at first to a concrete `MVector` type like `IOVector`. If you specialize the type of [`new`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#v:new), [`read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#v:read) and [`write`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html#v:write) to `IOVector`, you get the following, distinctively non-intimidating types:

```
new   :: Int -> IO (IOVector a)
read  :: IOVector a -> Int -> IO a
write :: IOVector a -> Int -> a -> IO ()
```

So for the first version, the implementation of your `Matrix` operations are straightforward:

```
import Data.Vector.Mutable as V
import Control.Monad (liftM)

data Matrix a = Matrix { size :: (Int, Int), buffer :: IOVector a }

newMatrix :: (Int, Int) -> IO (Matrix a)
newMatrix (w, h) = liftM (Matrix (w, h)) $ V.new (w * h)

set :: (Int, Int) -> a -> Matrix a -> IO ()
set pos e mtx = V.write (buffer mtx) (offset mtx pos) e

get :: (Int, Int) -> Matrix a -> IO a
get pos mtx = V.read (buffer mtx) (offset mtx pos)

offset :: Matrix a -> (Int, Int) -> Int
offset (Matrix (w, _h) _) (x, y) = w * y + x
```

So then, how do we generalize over the choice of `s` in `MVector s`? `Matrix` itself needs to be generalized over the choice of `s`:

```
data Matrix s a = Matrix { size :: (Int, Int), buffer :: MVector s a }
```

And we also need to thread this generalization through to all the functions. Let's look at `newMatrix` in detail; the rest can be left as an exercise for the reader.

If we just abstract on `s`, `newMatrix` becomes

```
newMatrix :: (Int, Int) -> IO (Matrix s a)
newMatrix (w, h) = liftM (Matrix (w, h)) $ V.new (w * h) -- Same implementation as above
```

However, surely this can't be right -- we can't create `MVector s a` in `IO` for any choice of `s`, only `RealWorld`! Expectedly, the typechecker catches this:

```
Couldn't match type `s' with `RealWorld'
  `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for newMatrix :: (Int, Int) -> IO (Matrix s a)
Expected type: s
  Actual type: PrimState IO
Expected type: IO (MVector s a)
  Actual type: IO (MVector (PrimState IO) a)
In the return type of a call of `new'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `new (w * h)'
```

But suppose we wrote

```
newMatrix :: (Monad m) => (Int, Int) -> m (Matrix s a)
```

This is, in some sense, even worse: now we are saying that for any choice of `m` and `s` (independent of each other!), we can construct a `Matrix s a` in `m`. Clearly this is not the case.

This is where the [`PrimMonad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Primitive.html#t:PrimMonad) typeclass is needed: it provides the linkage between `PrimState m`, the choice of `s`  for the vector being manipulated, and the monad `m` where this manipulation is possible. `newMatrix` thus becomes

```
newMatrix :: (PrimMonad m) => (Int, Int) -> m (Matrix (PrimState m) a)
newMatrix (w, h) = liftM (Matrix (w, h)) $ V.new (w * h) -- implementation is still the same!
```

The other operations can be typed in an analogous way.

Comment: Brilliant. Considering the state of the subject on the internet, I bet many will be learning from your post, coming from Google.